# When adding a scrollbar to my java swing program, it indents my JTextArea to the right

Tags: java, swing

I am using IntelliJ GUI Builder for my project. I am building a simple recipe manager. After adding a JTextArea, I decided to add a vertical scrollbar to see multiple recipes in the text area. the following is the .java code:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class viewPage extends JFrame {
    private JButton homeButton;
    private JPanel viewPage;
    private JTextArea viewArea;
    private JComboBox comboBox1;
    private JButton displayButton;
    private JScrollPane scroll;

    public viewPage() {
        viewArea.setText("");
        setContentPane(viewPage);
        setTitle("View Recipes");
        setSize(600, 700);
         addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                RecipeSerializer.serialize(Main.recipeList, "recipe.ser");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

       // scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        //scroll.setViewportView(viewArea);

        scroll.setBounds(100,100, 50,100);
        scroll.setViewportView(viewArea);
        viewArea.setLineWrap(true);
        viewArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        scroll.setViewportView(viewArea);

        setVisible(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < Main.recipeList.size(); ++i)
            viewArea.append(Main.recipeList.get(i).formattedToString());

        homeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                homePage p1 = new homePage();
                p1.show();
                dispose();

            }
        });
        displayButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int[] order = RecipeManager.sortRecipe(comboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());

                viewArea.setText("");
                for (int i = 0; i < Main.recipeList.size(); ++i)
                    viewArea.append(Main.recipeList.get(order[i]).formattedToString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The following is the auto-generated .form code generated by the GUI Builder

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns="http://www.intellij.com/uidesigner/form/" version="1" bind-to-class="viewPage">
  <grid id="27dc6" binding="viewPage" layout-manager="GridLayoutManager" row-count="5" column-count="7" same-size-horizontally="false" same-size-vertically="false" hgap="-1" vgap="-1">
    <margin top="20" left="20" bottom="20" right="20"/>
    <constraints>
      <xy x="20" y="20" width="457" height="400"/>
    </constraints>
    <properties/>
    <border type="none"/>
    <children>
      <component id="1ff19" class="javax.swing.JLabel">
        <constraints>
          <grid row="0" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="7" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="0" anchor="0" fill="0" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
        </constraints>
        <properties>
          <font name="Eras Demi ITC" size="28" style="1"/>
          <text value="View"/>
        </properties>
      </component>
      <hspacer id="86bc1">
        <constraints>
          <grid row="1" column="1" row-span="1" col-span="5" vsize-policy="1" hsize-policy="6" anchor="0" fill="1" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
        </constraints>
      </hspacer>
      <component id="3de99" class="javax.swing.JButton" binding="displayButton" default-binding="true">
        <constraints>
          <grid row="2" column="5" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="3" anchor="4" fill="0" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false">
            <preferred-size width="90" height="30"/>
          </grid>
        </constraints>
        <properties>
          <text value="Display"/>
        </properties>
      </component>
      <component id="fe26" class="javax.swing.JComboBox" binding="comboBox1" default-binding="true">
        <constraints>
          <grid row="2" column="4" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="2" anchor="4" fill="0" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false">
            <preferred-size width="187" height="30"/>
          </grid>
        </constraints>
        <properties>
          <model>
            <item value="Default"/>
            <item value="Title"/>
            <item value="Time"/>
            <item value="Type"/>
            <item value="Nr. Of Ingrediants"/>
          </model>
        </properties>
      </component>
      <component id="3c5b5" class="javax.swing.JLabel">
        <constraints>
          <grid row="2" column="3" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="0" anchor="4" fill="0" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
        </constraints>
        <properties>
          <horizontalAlignment value="4"/>
          <text value="Sort By"/>
        </properties>
      </component>
      <component id="12fa1" class="javax.swing.JButton" binding="homeButton" default-binding="true">
        <constraints>
          <grid row="4" column="4" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="0" hsize-policy="3" anchor="0" fill="1" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false">
            <preferred-size width="93" height="30"/>
          </grid>
        </constraints>
        <properties>
          <text value="Home"/>
        </properties>
      </component>
      <component id="1b77a" class="javax.swing.JTextArea" binding="viewArea">
        <constraints>
          <grid row="3" column="1" row-span="1" col-span="5" vsize-policy="3" hsize-policy="3" anchor="0" fill="3" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
        </constraints>
        <properties/>
      </component>
      <scrollpane id="38844" binding="scroll">
        <constraints>
          <grid row="3" column="6" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="7" hsize-policy="7" anchor="0" fill="3" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
        </constraints>
        <properties>
          <verticalScrollBarPolicy value="22"/>
        </properties>
        <border type="none"/>
        <children/>
      </scrollpane>
    </children>
  </grid>
</form>
```

Below you can see the image of how the window looks:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/thIP2.png]

I am looking to have the JTextArea span the entire window width and have the scrollbar there as well

Comment: *I am using IntelliJ GUI Builder for my project* - Don't. That will limit you to using that gui builder and code will not be portable in builders. Instead learn how to code the gui yourself and use layout managers effectively. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). I would keep the default BorderLayout of the frame and then add your scroll pane to the BorderLayout.CENTER. The other panels can be added to the BorderLayout.PAGE_START and BorderLayout.PAGE_END.

Comment: This is for my computer science course in high school, and while I do know how to code it from scratch this project was given with a very short due date, the teacher highly recommended us to use a GUI builder to work around the time constraint. Unfortunately, I am stuck using this.

Comment: Never Mind, I just put everything in a JPanel, It Works now!